# HTML to PDF conversion - Almost works, but

Tags: c#, pdf, response, file-conversion

I spent a good part of last few days searching for easy-to-use library that takes a html string as input, and produces PDF output as a file to the client browser.

Of the few dozen tools I tried out, a product called [NReco PDF Generator](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx), which is one of many derivative tools based on [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), seems to suit my needs.

Here's my test code:

```
var strHtml = String.Format("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");

(new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(strHtml, null, Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

With the above code, I expected to see a PDF file being passed to my browser. Instead, I only see the output stream being generated in my developer console. (BTW, I'm using Chrome)

My question is NOT about how the said product works, which I think is working as intended, but it is about whether my code is missing any action for the .NET's `Response` object or is doing anything wrong. As I already indicated, I can see the converted Pdf stream in the console. I think it's just a matter of capturing that stream in a file and passing it to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing line is `Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)`. Without that line the PDF will not be rendered to the user.

As far as I can tell you do not need the lines:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

The following works for me (Obviously, you need to add `using NReco.PdfGenerator;`)

```
string strHtml = String.Format("<h1>Hello World!</h1");
HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
var pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GeneratePdf(strHtml);

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline; filename=TEST.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the PDF as a byte array, then write it to the response.

```
var pdfBytes = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter().GeneratePdf(strHtml);
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
```

instead of

```
(new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(strHtml, null, Response.OutputStream);
```

Inspiration for this taken from [NReco's site](http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx).

Comment: Mason - This is one of several approaches I tried before and while it appears to work, I didn't see a PDF being passed to the browser.

Comment: Inspect the responses from the server using your browser's debugging tools. See if the file comes across or somehow gets embedded in the HTML document.